# firebase dataSnapshot.getValue() crashes android app

Tags: android, firebase, firebase-realtime-database, getvalue

I've put together a very simple android app to get used to using firebase on android. Following the getting started part of [Firebase's docs](https://firebase.google.com/docs/) I am able to write to the database with no issue. But when I go to retrieve that data with `getValue` from the database, the app crashes.

I try to read the database with the following code:

```
FirebaseDatabase database = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance();
DatabaseReference myRef = database.getReference("message");

ValueEventListener chatMessageListener = new ValueEventListener() {
  @Override
  public void onDataChange(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {
    TextView messages = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.old_messages);
    chatMessage ChatMessage = dataSnapshot.getValue(chatMessage.class);
    String message = dataSnapshot.toString();
  }

  @Override
  public void onCancelled(DatabaseError error) { 
    //.... 
  }
 };
myRef.addValueEventListener(chatMessageListener);
```

The JSON is very simple:
[this is taken from firebase, this data was provided from the app](https://i.stack.imgur.com/yAFbc.png)

I've also created "chatMessage" that was used for the writing the data:

```
@IgnoreExtraProperties
private static class chatMessage {
  public String message;
  public String messageFrom;
  public String messageTo;

  public chatMessage() {  }

  public chatMessage(String message, String messageFrom, String messageTo) {
    this.message = message;
    this.messageFrom = messageFrom;
    this.messageTo = messageTo;
  }

  public String getMessage(){
    return message;
  }

  public String getMessageFrom(){
    return messageFrom;
  }

  public String getMessageTo(){
    return messageTo;
  }
}
```

Comment: what problem are you facing? any error message?

Comment: When .getValue() executes the app will close, the error box pops up and says unfortunately the app has stoped . I tried with a child listener first and got the same result.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I see some issues with your code.

First your `chatMessage` class was not written in the java patterns. Every class name must start with an upper case letter.

```
private static class ChatMessage {
```

Your two constructors must also start with a capital letter

```
public ChatMessage() {  }
```

And in your `onDataChange`

```
ChatMessage chatMessage = dataSnapshot.getValue(ChatMessage.class);
```

also, you should be getting your message string using your `ChatMessage` object

```
String message = chatMessage.getMessage();
```

Comment: Looks like that was it. The crashing has gone away. It's not putting the text on the screen yet, but it looks like I'm in a way better position than I was.

Answer (score -1):

Try to stay away from camelCase writing (e.g. "messageFrom"). It seems that Firebase does not like capital letters for the labels

Answer (score -1):

change object into `String` using

```
String message = String.valueOf(dataSnapshot.getvalue());
```

instead of

```
String message = dataSnapshot.getvaluse().toString();
```